# Specify fixture to seed with seed fu plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have fixtures,

```
foo.rb
bar.rb
noo.rb
dar.rb
```

I there a way for me to seed only two fixtures.

```
rake db:seed_fu :only => [:foo, :noo]
```

Or any other way that can allow me to seed selected fixtures (without me deleting them or something like that)

Is there a way to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [documentation](https://github.com/mbleigh/seed-fu) under 'Rake task'

Only run seed files with a filename matching the FILTER

```
rake db:seed_fu FILTER=users,articles
```

Comment: Works, feel little embarrassed since I read it myself I guess I have to stop speed reading documentation. Again thanks great help.